# Spring security providers precedence

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have this configuration, where `activeDirectoryAuthenticationProvider` is a customized Active Directory provider. What I want to achieve, is that if database authentication fails, no further authentications are attempted.

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    JdbcUserDetailsManager udm = jdbcUserDetailsManager(ds);
    udm.setEnableGroups(true);
    udm.setEnableAuthorities(false);
    
    auth.userDetailsService(udm).passwordEncoder(userPasswordEncoder())
        .and().authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryAuthenticationProvider);
}
```

Current scenario is:

- I have a users databse with PK on the user name
- I have a database user with usernname `user` with some password with some permissions assigned
- I have an unrelated user `user` on active directory with a different password
- I login with the user and the password from *Active Directory*
- The user is logged in and gets the permissions from the database user

What I want is:

- Login fails, since database authentication has precedence over any other method (that's a biz requirement)

Is this achievable? How could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

SpringSecurity default providers chain don't know anything about priority of providers. Spring tries to authenticate via each provider until someone return Authentication object.

You need custom implementation of AuthenticationProvider, something like PrimaryOrientedAuthenticationProvider. I had a similar case. My implementitaion:

```java
public class PrimaryOrientedAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final AuthenticationProvider primaryAuthenticationProvider;
    private final AuthenticationProvider secondaryAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        Authentication auth;
        try {
            auth = primaryAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException | InternalAuthenticationServiceException ex) {
            log.debug("Trying to authenticate with secondary provider after exception", ex);
            return secondaryAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
        }

        if (auth == null) {
            log.debug("Trying to authenticate with secondary provider after no primary one was returned");
            return secondaryAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
        }

        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return primaryAuthenticationProvider.supports(authentication) &&
            secondaryAuthenticationProvider.supports(authentication);
    }
}
```

So, `activeDirectoryAuthenticationProvider` will try to authenticate only if `databaseAuthenticationProvider` will throw `UsernameNotFoundException` (user does not exist) or InternalAuthenticationServiceException (database not available for example).